# Return inserted ID in CrateDB

Tags: database, insert, crate

I already crawled through `CrateDB` documentation and didn't find any answer. How to return `_id` of last inserted record?

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to get this when inserting. you need to issue a query to get it. can you give an hint on the use-case to get a better understanding?